# Replace commas and whitespace c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

how can i replace the commas and whitespaces in a string with `-` I have tried this:

`FeatureIds = Regex.Replace(config.FeaturePacks, @"[, ]", "-"),`

But it is replacing it with 2 `-` like so:

`F0--F1--F2`

The input string is like so:

F0, F1, F2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for *one or more* after the character class `[, ]` so it becomes:

```
[, ]+
```

[Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cE6yH4/1)

If "whitespace" also means newlines, change to `[,\s]+` where `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]`

Answer (score 0):

Use " *, *" instead. This will match any number of spaces, then a comma, and again any number of spaces. [See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/rX9fQ9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
, | ,|[, ]
```

Try this.Replace by `-`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/68

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use the replace function instead of a Regex?

```
FeatureIds = config.FeaturePacks.Replace(", ", "-");
```

Comment: No, because it does not work on one or multiple consecutive spaces or a comma without space. -1